# Change select options when other select is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I currently have something where you select the country your in USA or Canada and right now I have all the american states in another select I want this select to change to the Canada provinces when It is changed to canada. Here is my code:

```
<select class="select optional" id="state" name="order[billing_state]">

 <option value=""></option>

 <option value="AL">AL</option>

<option value="AK">AK</option>

<option value="AS">AS</option>
etc...
```

here is the country part:

```
<select class="select optional" id="country"> 

   <option selected="selected" value="USA">USA</option> 

   <option value="CANADA">CANADA</option> 

</select>
```

How would I get the states to change to canadian provinces when I change the select to Canada.

I also have a couple other selects I am messing around with so knowing how to make something when the select is changed to a certain option to do something would be very helpful to me.

Anything helps thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using jQuery, this should be achievable via the following code:

```
<script>


 $(function() {        
  // updates the state select based on specified country
  function updateStateSelect(country) {   

    var states = []    
    if(country === 'USA') {    
      // states for usa
      states = [
        '',
        'AL',
        'AK',
        'AS', 
      ]
    }
    else {    
      // states for can
      states = [
        '',
        'BC', 
      ]
    }

    var stateSelect = $('#state');

    // empty any previous options in state select  
    stateSelect.empty();    

    // iterate states in selected country, and add options to 
    // state select
    for(var state of states) {
      stateSelect.append(
          $('<option value="' + state + '">' + state + '</option>'))
    }    
  }

  // configure your country select to update state select when changed
  $('#country')
  .change(function() {

    // when the country select is changed, update the state 
    // select based on current selected country 
    updateStateSelect($(this).val())
  })
  .change() // cause state select to be initialised by firing the 
            // change handler

})
</script>
```

This script should be able to be plugged in anywhere to your page and it should work as expected. Additionally, it will preserve the correct option values for each state of the currently selected country.

[There's a working example here on jsFiddle for you to try](https://jsfiddle.net/mfxyL5h4/2/)

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]        the one on the first defined states   (  states = [
        '',
        'AL',
        'AK',
        'AS',
        ...
      ]   )

Comment: I did and this was the error I got.     this.val is not a function

Comment: it was not able to recognize name = billing_state so I changed it to ("#state")  and then I got this error...   value is not defined..  and it pointed to   $('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'))  and this...    updateStateSelect($(this).val())

Comment: Hi please see updates with working jsFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/mfxyL5h4/2/

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help....

```js
$('#country').change(function() {
  var country = $(this).val();
  $('#states').children().each(function(index, option) {
    var i = 0;
    if ($(option).attr('data-country') == country) {
      $(this).show();
      if (i == 0) {
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
      }
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country">
  <option value="usa">USA</option>
  <option value="canada">Canada</option>
</select>

<select id="states">
  <option value="CA" data-country="usa">CA</option>
  <option value="Ontario" data-country="canada">Ontario</option>
  <option value="texas" data-country="usa">Texas</option>
  <option value="CA" data-country="canada">Alberta</option>
  <!--
  some more states.....
  -->
</select>
```

Let me know if this solve your problem or any issue you have...

Comment: @MaxymWojnowskyj whats the problem??

Comment: i added in the american states and the canada stuff with the data-country and it just has the Canada provinces and the states all inside the select and doesn't hide any options

Comment: It working in the snippet above. I did get you problem properly @MaxymWojnowskyj

Comment: When I change the select to canada and click on the states select no options pops up I cant click on it